# Google Artifacts vulnerability report - On demand image scanning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-artifact-registry

I have scenario where I am using GCP an on-demand image scanning using gcloud - like:

### gcloud artifacts docker images scan europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ORG_NAME/myrepo/python_script@sha256:4e3dd2d724ded3cc434ec9fdc33bdfdab1c0d579430b64c9baf4ecb901115b05 --remote --location=europe

And its working fine and I can retrieve the vulnerability scan report using:

### gcloud artifacts docker images list-vulnerabilities projects/ORG_NAME/locations/europe/scans/661e3c2a-c27c-6617-9088-80c7d40e14b8

Now the problem that this report doesn't appear on the artifacts dashboard like it does for auto scanning.

Auto Scanned Image:
[Auto Scanned Image - Vulnerability Scan report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9VAF.jpg)

Any idea how can I make this on demand scanning report to show on artifacts dashboard for the particular image.

I have tried to look for storing artifacts metadata: https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/metadata-storage - but I can't find a way to store the data and make it appear on the artifacts dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifacts dashboard only provides data for containers that were [scanned automatically](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/automated-scanning-howto).  `Gcloud` is the preferred way to retrieve vulnerability data from On Demand Scanning.